# Perform group by with random group expression (randomly partitioning rows) MYSQL

Tags: mysql, random

Let's say I have a table (with millions of rows)

```
cat1|cat2|value
A   |   B|   10 
...
```

and I want to group the data by `cat1` and also split the grouping into 10 (at least roughly) equal partitions of the data.

The purpose of the random grouping is for the machine learning technique of cross-validation.  (It's similar to splitting subjects into a control group and experimental group.)

What I would imagine to use is the following:

```
select cat1, r, sum(value)
from t 
group by cat1, floor(rand()*10) as r
```

which doesn't work.

One way which I believe would work would be simply to insert a new column with rand into my table and then group appropriately on that.

Is there any way of doing this grouping otherwise?

Comment: Don't you need to store the grouping assignment for each row so that the groupings can be replicated at a later date? Is it a business requirement that the groupings be random, or is it simply necessary that they roughly equal and non-contiguous?

Comment: @pieter - yes it should be random and non contiguous. I don't really need to store grouping assignment (but I should be able to recreate if pass same random number? - rows are not updated)

Comment: This would work: `select cat1, r, sum(value) from (select cat1, value, floor(rand()*10) as r from t) as x group by cat1, r ;`

Answer (score 1):

Your post piqued my curiosity and I look at the RAND() function - which you can't perform GROUP BYs with. I found [this](https://www.flamingspork.com/blog/2009/02/02/row-id-in-mysql-and-drizzle-and-the-engines/) and if your table has a PRIMARY KEY, there is a MySQL pseudo-column (_rowid), much like is found in Oracle, Firebird (and maybe others) then you can issue queries such as this one (see structure and data for comments table (sample) below).

```
select MOD(_rowid, 3) AS my_field, COUNT(ticket_id) 
FROM comments 
GROUP BY my_field;

+----------+------------------+
| my_field | count(ticket_id) |
+----------+------------------+
|        0 |                6 |
|        1 |                7 |
|        2 |                7 |
+----------+------------------+
```

Now, if your PK is some sort of AUTO INCREMENT and "random" with respect to your data, you could perhaps use the _rowid pseudo-column (with MOD) to generate a sufficient degree of randomness for your requirements, and perform your aggregate queries?

---- structure and data in comments table---

```
CREATE TABLE `comments` 
(
  `comment_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `ticket_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`comment_id`)
);


mysql> SELECT * FROM comments;
+------------+-----------+
| comment_id | ticket_id |
+------------+-----------+
|          1 |         1 |
|          2 |         1 |
|          3 |         1 |
|          4 |         1 |
|          5 |         2 |
|          6 |         2 |
|          7 |         2 |
|          8 |         2 |
|          9 |         3 |
|         10 |         3 |
|         11 |         3 |
|         12 |         3 |
|         13 |         4 |
|         14 |         4 |
|         15 |         4 |
|         16 |         4 |
|         17 |         5 |
|         18 |         5 |
|         19 |         5 |
|         20 |         5 |
+------------+-----------+
```

Answer (score -1):

My understanding is that functions, such as `rand()`, are executed once per column reference to in SQL.  Thus any query which scans the whole table will produce the same "random" value for every row.  I think you're going to have to iterate through your data setting random numbers one at a time, [RBAR](https://www.simple-talk.com/sql/t-sql-programming/rbar--row-by-agonizing-row/)-stylie.

Comment: Why the down vote?

Comment: I guess because what you say about `RAND()` is not true in MySQL: [SQL-Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/91e4b/1) (I guess you  confused this issue with SQL-Server)